# Cache resource files to improve performance

Tags: asp.net, caching, localization, globalization, resx

I want to cache resource files to improve performance.
Are resource files actually cached?

When i get a value from resources file like this:

```
Label1.text=   Resource1.String1
```

The resourcemanager get it from memory/ compiled c# code?
or the value is retrieved each time from a serialized string in a file

```
  <data name="String1" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: Are these localized resources?

Comment: it is the same i'm looking for a way to cache it,if i should use global resources i will use global resources otherwise i will go local

Answer (score 4):

It's automatically cached, no matter if it is local or global.
Assuming you are using the default resx provider.